# Implementing oauth in a Rails app: one user model or two (user + authentication)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

On my journey to learning Rails, I'm making my first foray into oauth territory. I have a User model, and plan to allow users to connect to several services. I expect this will be a fixed list of services, i.e. I don't anticipate adding new authentication services in the future (though never say never, right?).

So, I can see two ways of proceeding.

1. Have an uber User model that, as well as holding username, password, etc also stores fb_uid, twitter_uid, etc and any data pulled from those services.
2. Have a User model, and an associated Auth_Services model. Username, password, etc goes in Users. Uid, user_id, provider name, oauth data, etc goes in Auth_Services.

I can see advantages and drawbacks in both approaches. I can see opinions with regard to normalized database design with both approaches.

So my question, for people who have done this before, which route did you use, and why? What issues did you run into, and what should I be thinking about or planning for when making a  decision?

Thanks for helping me learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is even the slightest possibility you will add further authentications, gotta go with the two models. That was my reason anyway.

Comment: hi wachichomia, thanks for the suggestion. I can more or less understand the "good database design" aspects of this question. I suppose what I'm really after is some insights into how either approach may affect business logic, user flows, etc. I'm just beginning to experiment with oauth, and at this stage I'm not really sure what kind of issues to expect. Gratefully for any advise from this who have been here before. No one has come back saying "that's an awful idea, don't do that", which I guess is a good sign. Right? Thanks again

Comment: actually, what is troubling me here is the differences in data between each service. For example, if I want to store data about the user returned by the oauth request, while there are similarities between returned data, there may be differences. This makes the design of the Authentication model more complex. For example, I may want to store the user's Twitter nickname, and their Facebook timezone and location. So I'll need a separate column for each service's fields. Or is there a better way? Could I store the access_token itself in a data field? Wondering how others have tackled this.

Comment: I went with separate user and authentication models. I included a hash column in the auth model to store unstructured data, allowing different atrributes to be stored for each provider.

Comment: @AndyHarvey: that's the approach I like to take as well. From a practical standpoint, I have found that as the User table grows large in size, it becomes increasingly cumbersome to add additional columns to it with each new service you want to add.